# Failed to load resource: app/app.module

Tags: angular

I am getting the subject error, while loading the a html page from IISExpress.

> " Error loading http://localhost:7041/src/app/app.module as
>   "./app/app.module" from http://localhost:7041/src/main.js "

I am following a generic directory structure. i.e src-> app-> app.module.ts and other ts files.
main.js is available under src.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: i am using visual studio, it compiles the application successfully. project is web api and angular is used to call the controller and display the response in a html.

do i need to do use ng build as well ?

Comment: Did you create your project using `angular-cli`?

Comment: i have taken quick  master sample from git hub. created new web project in VS and included the necessary files for angular to work. 

i did build once using npm start which in turn invokes tsc ...., lite server  so that works fine and i get the output.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related to path mappings of the javascript files referenced in the html, which Visual studio accepts differently. video on you tube helped this to close. thank you.